# Generate 2 different combinations on the same line?

Tags: python, combinations

How would I generate 2 different combinations on the same line from lower a and lower b together but only generate from each own brackets?

```
import itertools

lower_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

lower_b = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
num_c = ['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']

all = []
all = num + lower_a  + num_c + lower_b 

  for r in range(4, 5):
     for s in itertools.product(all, repeat=r):
     print ''.join(s) + ''.join(s)
```

The outputs something like the following vs Want I would like the code to do

```
00000000

00010001

00020002

00030003

00040004

00050005

00060006

00070007

00080008

00090009

000a000a

000b000b





00009999 

00019998 

00029997 

00039996 

00049995
```

Comment: What would you like the output to be?

Comment: 00009999 00019998 00029997 00039996 00049995

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools as it

lower_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

lower_b = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
num_c = ['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']

all_a = num + lower_a
all_b = num_c + lower_b
all_c = ['0', '2', '4', '6', '8', '1', '3', '5', '7', '9', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r']

a_repeat = 4
b_repeat = 5
c_repeat = 6

for r, s, t in it.izip(it.product(all_a, repeat=a_repeat),
                       it.product(all_b, repeat=b_repeat),
                       it.product(all_c, repeat=c_repeat)):
    print ''.join(r) + ''.join(s) + ''.join(t)
```

Comment: Yes that's it, thanks but for part: for r in range(4, 5) how would I put 2 different lengths, example: for r in range(4, 5 + 5, 6) 000099999

Comment: @DonVito I added two variables to my answer that you can change.

Comment: I was trying to add an extra set to it, all_c, it.product(all_c, repeat=c_repeat)) but it said 'ValueError: too many values to unpack' is it possible to add 3 or more combinations to the first 2. Like keep adding sets to the same line? I'm working on that bottom part

Comment: @DonVito Also, if I answered your *original* question, be sure to mark it as accepted with the green checkmark on the right. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok, and another thing, how to loop it, if I wanted to force stop it?

Comment: What do you mean "how to loop it, if I wanted to force stop it"? You mean hit Ctrl+C?

Comment: Yes, how to put it in infinite loop until I force it to stop manually.

Comment: Why do you need an infinite loop? Does Ctrl+C not do what you need?

Comment: I want the combinations to keep going and not stop, I'm going to add something else to it, but the combinations stop, I want it keep printing looping.

Comment: The combinations will not loop forever, simply because there are a finite number of combinations. Do you want to have the same set of combinations print over and over again? Please note that you are deviating from your original question. I will try to help you, but please don't do this again in the future. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Do you want to have the same set of combinations print over and over again? Yes I want it to keep printing it over and over. I just had came up with an idea.

Comment: Does wrapping the printing `for` loop in a `while True:` loop accomplish what you want?

Comment: where do I put that at the beginning of the code or a the bottom where printing is, because I put it at the top above lower_a and it stalls, it won't print

Comment: *"wrapping the printing `for` loop in a `while True:`"* is what I said. I think it's pretty clear: put the `while True:` above the `for` loop.

Comment: Again, accepting the answer would indicate that the question has been solved (the original question has actually been solved long ago **;)**) and would remove this question from the "Unanswered" queue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers